# Update content in static UITableViewCell from Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift

I have a **UITableViewController** with ***static cells***, and the next screen is a View to Add new entries with Core Data, this all works fine and inserts the values correctly into the database.

[image: Navigation and Table View Controller]

Inside each of the static cells, I have a label which I refer to with an `@IBOutlet` reference.

In Core Data, for instance, one of the attributes of my `Entity` model is **booksNumber**. Every time I add a new record to my database I want my `numBooksLabel` inside my static cell of the table view **to update and show the total number of all books** I have added. But I don't know *where* to perform this logic.

My code related to the table view looks like this:

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController,
    didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject,
    atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath,
    forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
    newIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        // cell.textLabel?.text = "something"
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Move:
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

**I have no `tableView override functions`** as I believe they are not necessary for static cells UITableViews, correct me if I'm wrong.

Sorry if it's a trivial question but I'm brand new to Swift and to the whole xCode world and would really appreciate some help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to insert table rows, you should use Dynamic Prototypes instead of static cell. because static cell is for fixed rows count.

Comment: I have a fixed rows count, as I said before, so static cell its OK...

Comment: That controller:didChangeObject: code is the boilerplate code to update a table view which has one row for every object.  If you only want to update the label in one row with the number of objects, you should replace that code with something like: `numBooksLabel.text = "\(self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count)"`

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf, I did something similar to what you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finnally solved it thanks to some gentle co-worker advice!

This is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var booksLabel: UILabel!

// Report logic inside event
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    var books = 0
    let entities = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as [Entity]

    for e in entities {
        if e.books != nil {
            books += e.books as Int
        }
    }

    self.booksLabel.text = String(books)
}
```

I hope it may help someone else.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! It helped me a lot :) Do you know how can I do if I'm using static cells to save different values? For ex.: You have one cell with books, what if I add a different cell with authors, how can you save both without creating a new record in core data? I'm working on a personal information page were the user can put a bio, favourites, activities and save that data from all those static cells into core data.

Comment: @Lucas it would be exactly the same, Entity is my class and it contains many properties, I just used the books one as an example but I also had others inside that class as well. You just do all the logic inside the viewWillAppear function and then update the corresponding label for your static cells ;)